# ModuleNotFoundError when importing ‘keyboard’ in Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, keyboard

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cynthia0890/docs/lottery.py", line 3, ...
    import keyboard
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keyboard'
root@penguin: /home/cynthia0890 #
```

Here’s the story in a few words. Lottery game. Import keyboard. Linux root. ModuleNotFoundError. Why is there a ModuleNotFoundError on the import ‘keyboard’?

The `keyboard` module is an [official module available in the repositories](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/), so why am I getting a error?

Here’s a code snippet of the import and what I am using it for.

```py
import keyboard

if userNums == winningNums:
    print(“\nCongratulations! You won the jackpot!”)
    print(“Press M to return to the menu.”)
    if keyboard.is_pressed(“m”):
        printMenu()
    else:
        print(“Please press M to return to the menu!”)
```

Comment: Have you run `pip install keyboard`?

Comment: Yes.  I ran pip install keyboard, it should be version 0.13.5.

Comment: Is there any chance you have multiple versions of Python installed?

Comment: No. Only version 3.9.2.

Answer (score 0):

(edited)

after a small search I found same problem and I found that the problem was solved by did the next install instruction

`python -m pip install keyboard`

after you install it close your ide then open it, it should be done.

Comment: I did that, ran the program in root, and it gave me the error.

Comment: does the keybaord installed?

Comment: I think I found it

Comment: I tried that command, it says the requirement is already satisfied and the module is installed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have multiple Python environments. And you have selected the python interpreter which has not installed the `keyboard` module.

Could you check where you have installed the `keyboard` module through `pip show keyboard`? And which python interpreter you have selected from the bottom-left on the VSCode?